# Error in passing the hidden values to JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Problem with passing values to Javascript, am I going wrong in passing the value pls help.

```
var percentage= parseInt(document.getElementById("<%=hid_Percentage.ClientID%>").value);
        var color = document.getElementById("<%=hid_Color.ClientID%>").value;
        var progress1 = new RGraph.VProgress('progress1', percentage, 100);
                    progress1.Set('chart.colors', [color]);
                    progress1.Set('chart.tickmarks', false);
                    progress1.Draw();
```

I have 2 hidden fields

```
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hid_Percentage" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hid_Color" runat="server" />
```

And this is how I pass value to the hidden field in code behind in asp.net

```
        double value = (read * 100 / count);
        string vProgressColor = "'#e01600'";
        hid_Percentage.Value = Convert.ToString(value);
        hid_Color.Value = vProgressColor;
```

The value for percentage is passed correclty as the graph is drawn using that value. But the color is emply. it is not getting the color.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. I would put an `alert(color);` to double check. If you get the colour printed out, it means the problem is in the `RGraph.VProgress`.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt here:

string vProgressColor = "'#e01600'";

try removing ' ' from your string value

string vProgressColor = "#e01600";